# Update workflow settings of existing workflow attached to a list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, powershell, script

Workflows can be set to trigger on item created, item updated, manually and etc.

I have a workflow attached to a list which is by default set to be triggered on item create event. Using powershell I migrate some data to this list.
So i need to change the settings of existing workflow not to start on item created event and set it to trigger on item created after i migrate my data.

how to update this property\ setting of workflow using powershell.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't done this in powershell but I expect that you can use the same classes and methods. If it's a SharePoint 2013 workflow you can query the workflows for a list using "EnumerateSubscriptionsByList" from "WorkflowSubscriptionService" class and change EventType property which is used to indicate the event on which the workflow should start. Here is a related post and question with code examples for powerhshell:

[SharePoint 2013 Reusable workflow doesn't pick up fields in a different site collection](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/184541/sharepoint-2013-reusable-workflow-doesnt-pick-up-fields-in-a-different-site-col)

https://jesperarnecke.wordpress.com/2014/04/02/sharepoint-2013-workflow-management-starting-a-workflow-using-powershell/

Comment: Workflow attachment to a list can be done no issue. The problem i have is how to change a property and how to apply changes (update Workflow Subscription service\ list \ web)

Comment: Updating is possible by getting the subscription, updating the properties and publishing it again (PublishSubscriptionForList).

Comment: $workflowServiceManager = New-object Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager($web)
   $workflowSubscriptionService = $workflowServiceManager.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService()
   $wf = $workflowSubscriptionService.EnumerateSubscriptionsByList($list.ID) | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $workflowName}
   $wf.SetProperty("EventTypes", 'ItemUpdated');
   $workflowSubscriptionService.PublishSubscriptionForList($wf,$list.ID);

it did not work

Comment: Did you check what kind of input is expected for EventType? There is a property called EventType (at least in CSOM) so you don't have to use SetProperty. Here is an example of how EventTypes should be supplied: https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/working-with-the-sharepoint-workflow-services-client-side-object-model. Also make sure to perform ExecuteQuery after publish.

Comment: Its pure powershell i'm working on. So no CSOM or ExecuteQuery.

Comment: Following notation for Event types:
    #Build start options
    $startOptions = New-Object "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.String]"
    $startOptions.Add("ItemAdded") #When item added
    $startOptions.Add("ItemUpdated") #When item updated
    $startOptions.Add("WorkflowStart") #Allow manual start
    $sub.EventTypes = $startOptions

Comment: Yep, it worked. Thanks and ill update the solution with full code segment.